# Installing Ubuntu on HP envy x360 15cn does not detect the PCIe NVMe SSD drive

Tags: ssd, hp, nvme, pcie

I have a HP envy x360 laptop. 
I have 2 two disks on it.

```
1. PCIe NVMe SSD 500GB(windows pre-installed)
2. SATA Seagate HDD 1TB
```

I tried installing many linux operating systems on it including Ubuntu, but the installer cannot detect the SSD drive only the HDD.

How can I troubleshoot this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

did you ever find an answer for this? I've been trying to install ubuntu on my x360 15m. I only have 1 SSD and the installer cannot see it.

In my research, I did see a situation where if you have 2 drives, you have to install and boot with just one, and then after you know it can boot, add the 2nd drive.

Comment: Many systems need both UEFI update from vendor and SSD firmware update for SSD.

Comment: Hi Collin, I tried installing many other linux distros by creating bootable USBs, none of them could see the PCIe NVMe SSD. I have now replaced the the SATA HDD with the SATA SSD. Now I installed the Arcolinux(an Arch spinoff) on the SATA SSD. The PCIe NVMe SSD is still lying unused ;)